# Selenium Webdriver: NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am stuck on it for a while now, so I thought I shall ask for help.
I am trying to locate an element by name using page factory mechanism which uses in built findElement API. Element is there on web page, but still it cannot find it. Can anyone please point where I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "userName")
private WebElement userName;

public WebElement getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

homepage.getUserName().sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: Adding more information about error logs:   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"userName"}
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. However you might need to add a wait before sendKeys since it might be possible that the page isn't loaded by that time.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,5));
wait.Until(By.Id("login"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Sakshi. Adding wait helped me to find the root cause. I was able to see it after adding wait that it was trying to find the elements on empty page as the junit tests are run in non-deterministic order :) I fixed it by making my tests independent of each other. I am now starting each test with a clean state(by opening web site from start for each run) Everything works good now.  I also found that in JUnit 4.1.2 we can now control the order in which tests are run using "@FixMethodOrder", but I prefer not to do that as tests should run independently.

Comment: @Tajinder: if this answers your query, then please mark it as an answer